# Send select multiple value to create an issue in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am using Jira rest API to create an issue like this

```
IssueRestClient issueClient = getJiraRestClient().getIssueClient();
    IssueInputBuilder newIssue = new IssueInputBuilder(projectKey, issueType, issueSummary);    
    if (list != null) {
        for (Fields field : list) {                             
                newIssue.setFieldValue("customfield_" + field.getIdJira(), field.getValue());               
        }
    }
    IssueInput issueInput = newIssue.build();
```

But i don't know how to do it with mutiple select value like `Gender` :`Man`OR `Woman` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quiet simple

```
newIssue.setFieldValue("customfield_" + field.getIdJira(),
                        ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("value", field.getValue()));
```

In my case `field.getIdJira()` is holding the `ID` of the `customfield` and `field.getValue()` is holding the actuel value of the field.